# allow user to choose from his own referenced nodes

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have two content types: business listing, product listing.
"Product listing" has an Entity Reference field. This field points to the nodes of "business listing".
I want to allow user to choose from his own "business listing" nodes (during adding a "product listing" node).
I have created a view to list the nodes of "business listing" type and have Added a Entity Reference display to the view. Then have selected the view Under "Entity selection".
Now, I have a problem in adding proper contextual filter.
I have added a contextual filter of "Content: Author Uid" and selected "provide default value".

a) if I select "USER ID from logged in user" as default value:

This solution will break if an admin is editing the node. The field will then show only nodes the current user (admin) has created.

b) if I select {"User ID from URL" and "Also look for a node and use the node author"}:
This solution will break if an user is adding a new node. The field will not show any nodes!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `I want to allow user to choose from his ` **own** `"business listing" nodes.` please explain why `a)` is a problem?

Comment: hi, if an admin is editing the nodes of other users. the field will show only nodes the current user (Admin) has created (admin is logged user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For type: select PHP Code

[image]

and put this code in there.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . request_uri();
$getnid = explode("/", $url);
$var = $getnid[2];

if (is_numeric($var)) { 

  $node = node_load($var);
  return $node->uid;

} else { 

  global $user;
  return $user->uid;

}
```

**Explanation of code**

Line 1 gets the current page url

Line 2 implements the [explode php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Line 3 grabs the 2nd `/` from the url

Then we use an if statement to check if line 3 is a number or not:

- If it is a number then it has to be the `node/2/edit` form. The `2` is the nid, which we then use to grab the author (uid).
- Else, if it's not a number, then we know that it is the `node/add` form. So since it doesn't have a number in the url, we use the logged in user uid instead.

Comment: Is there an advantage to getting the argument that way instead of using arg(#)?

Answer (score 1):

No need to write any code for this.
Use [reference_option_limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module properly in your content types & when you create view and provide default value 'User ID from URL' - Please mark the checkbox 'Also look for a node and use the node author' to true.

Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the author uid to the url for creation and editing.

node/add/contenttype/123 and node/#/edit/123 where 123 is the current user during creation and is the author during edit.

Make your entity reference view pick the raw value from url.

Comment: By using tokens or replacement patterns for the create node and edit node links. The entity reference view raw value should be 4 I think. How does a user create a new node at the moment?

Comment: I have tried to use tokens by pathauto.

Comment: now, my url is : example.com/node/add

Comment: You'd need to create a new place for node add links.. In a block or menu. The links would be node/add/article/123 for example.

Comment: Although I can see this method working, it's an ugly way to solve the problem.

Comment: Agreed.. But I had to do it for a field collection. node/123/edit/456 where 123 was the node and 456 was the argument for the entity reference field inside the field collection. Couldn't think of a better way.