# How do I filter an entityreference field based on other fields?

Tags: entities, views

So I'm trying to create a node that has an entityreference to another node. THing is I need that field to filter the data from an entityreference view based on three use cases.

1. New content. Should only show referenced nodes created by the same user.
2. Editing created content. Should only show referenced nodes created by the person who created the edited node
3. New Content as Admin - An administrator/editor should be able to add content under another users name, and it should filter and show nodes created by that user.

I've got 2 out of three but I'm not sure how to get the last one done.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me of this [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192893/allow-user-to-choose-from-his-own-referenced-nodes) you may or may not find it relevant.

Alternatively, you could use [Masquarde](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade)

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with
>   enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no
>   password required). That person can switch back to their own user
>   account at any time.

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYETIJfKUIo)

Comment: Yea, I forgot I had written out that question unfortunately.

The module you are linking me to look slike it might actually be something I should have since this is a community site and I get a lot of comments about things they see I don't. I'll be using it I think though for me and other admin.

I think the solution now might not be through the view but through a prepopulate link created in views for each story on administration. It's a thought.